# Use linux command ping assynchronously using a channel

Tags: tcl, channel

I'm trying to use channels to be able to ping a lot of machines in a parallelized way so to have the information needed in a short notice.

One of the attempts made is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# the next line restarts using tclsh \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}

proc pingHandler {pipe host} {
    set line [gets $pipe]
    if {[eof $pipe]} {
        close $pipe
        puts "All done."
        chan event $pipe readable {}
        set pipe_exit 1
        return
    }
    puts "line: $line"
}
proc pingAsync {} {
    set hostnames [list devuan alpine 192.168.1.253]
    foreach host $hostnames {
        puts "... $host"
        set pipe [open |[list ping -c 1 $host]]
        chan event $pipe readable [list pingHandler $pipe $host]
    }
    puts "processing..."
}
pingAsync
vwait pipe_exit
```

What happens is that when a ping is tried and the host doesn't respond to the query, subsequent hostnames in the list are only queried after that response.
I haven't been able to spot where the issue is.

Edit:
For not resolvable hosts, the stderr should be redirected to stdout, like: `|[list ping -c 1 $host 2>@1]`

Comment: You don't need to remove the handler after closing. Handlers are removed once a channel is fully closed (i.e., on unregistration of the channel name); the distinction matters because some channel types can be half-closed (notably sockets and bidirectional pipes). In this case, you've got a unidirectional pipe so the fine detail isn't critical.

Comment: The channel doesn't even exist anymore at that point. Trying to remove the handler actually results in an error: can not find channel named "file3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

- make pipe_exit and hostnames global variables defined at the top of the script

  ```
  set pipe_exit 0
  set hostnames [list devuan alpine 192.168.1.253]
  ```
- instead of `set pipe_exit`, use `incr ::pipe_exit`
- because hostnames is global, you'll need `foreach host $::hostnames`
- then the vwait command can be

  ```
  while {$pipe_exit < [llength $hostnames]} {
      vwait pipe_exit
  }
  ```

Comment: The shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env tclsh` works too

Comment: The answers are complementary.  But it's the first time I deal with vwait and hadn't grasp I could do such a expression, so I choose this answer as the accepted answer.  Thank you, Glenn.

Answer (score 2):

Your pingHandler is called whenever there is new data available on the channel. That doesn't necessarily have to be a full line. But because your channel is in blocking mode (the default), the `gets` command will wait for the rest of the line. Apparently your ping to an unreachable host produces some partial line, with the rest only happening after a timeout.

The first step to solving this, is to configure the channel to be non-blocking:

```
set pipe [open |[list ping -c 1 $host]]
chan configure $pipe -blocking 0
```

You'll run into other issues with your code after that, but I'll leave those for you to fix.

Comment: Good, thank you.
Indeed, there are two more problems.   One, for not resolvable hosts.  Ping returns an error, so stderr should be redirected to stdout.  I already edited my post.

Comment: The other one is that `vwait` is waiting for `pipe_exit`, but `pipe_exit` is being set to 1 for each pipe opened.  This one I haven't yet figured out how to solve.  Maybe create a different `pipe_exit` for each pinged host?  Like `pipe_exit${host}`?